# Responsive Table - How to group columns of a table to achieve the result below?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a table that on mobile should display as the second image below and clicking on the header (orange portion) should collapse (show and hide) the white party.

How can I group the columns? That is the portion that is giving me a hard time. I tried a few thing but no success so far. I tried using `divs` inside `<table>`, `<tbody>` and `<tr>` but I learned that this is not acceptable and in fact the divs get spilled out of the table on the DOM. I tried using `<colgroup>` and `<col>` but those stop behaving well once I change the display to the `<table>` or `<tr>` to inline displays or flex.

I was able to achieve this using `salesforce` aura but can't figure how to do it with pure `html` and `css`.

You can follow my work on this matter live at: http://codepen.io/vinicius5581/pen/XXKGwx

Here is one of my failed attempts. Please note that once I apply flex to the `<tr>`, I lose completely the `<colgroup>`.

```css
*{border:0;margin:0;padding:0;}
thead{
  display:none;
}
.mob-header{
  background:red;
}
tr{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
td{
  width: 100%; 
}

td:nth-of-type(1){
  width: 50%;
  order: 1;
}
td:nth-of-type(2){
  width: 50%;
  order: 2;
}
td:nth-of-type(3){
  width: 50%;
  order: 3;
}
td:nth-of-type(4){
  width: 100%;
  order: 5;
  float:right;
}
td:nth-of-type(5){
  width: 50%;
  order: 4;
}

td:nth-of-type(4)::before{
  content:'Header 4';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup class="mob-header" span="3"></colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>CEL 1A</td>
      <td>CEL 2A</td>
      <td>CEL 3A</td>
      <td>CEL 4A</td>
      <td>CEL 5A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CEL 1B</td>
      <td>CEL 2B</td>
      <td>CEL 3B</td>
      <td>CEL 4B</td>
      <td>CEL 5B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is welcome. Tnx. ;)

[image: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1T6B_6DC41BAz0wG5wnnWGcKkNkfIpKAzzL-Bv8wwcbI/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: I'm confused, why does header4 appear twice in the second table, and why are the headers white and the rows orange?